# MS Access 2010: Query time and speed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am running the following insert query in MS Access 2010, and I need a way for the query to run faster.  I do need to get all of the columns from the Source_1_table into the temp_Table.

- Source_1_table has 505K records
- Source_2_table has 3959 records

  INSERT INTO [temp_Table] 
  SELECT * 
  FROM Source_1_table
  WHERE 
  ((dbo_Source_1_table.Field_1)) Not IN (SELECT [Source_2_table].[ID_Field] FROM [Source_2_table]));

Question 1. How do I see how long it is taking the query to run (similar to SSMS)?
Question 2. The query seems to be taking longer than 10 minutes to run.  Is there any way speed up this query?

Comment: Is this linking to a table in SQL Server, is it local, or is it on a different DB? You may want to look into Pass-Through Queries. Also, I doubt it would make a difference, but consider switching the positions of the table to check small > big rather than big > small.

Comment: Do you have indexes defined for the two columns referenced in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with that many records in an Access db before, so I'm not surprised it's slow.

I solved a similar problem recently in some legacy code. I think a big problem is that you are running your subquery once for every record in the main query (someone please correct me if that's not correct). Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO [temp_Table] 
SELECT s1.* 
    FROM Source_1_table s1
    Left Join Source_1_table s2 on s1.Field_1=s2.ID_Field
    where s2.ID_Field is null
```